# Angular 6 Mat-Dialog hides a part of the background webpage

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-material-6

So, I have been using Mat-Dialog to show popups and dialogs, and I have just discovered this issue. A part of the background page(the page from which I open the modal) gets hidden when i scroll down on that page and try opening a dialog box. This issue is not found when the page is at the top.

[image: The problem I face when I scroll down on a webpage and open a dialog]

I have no idea how to express this issue properly to you guys but, can y'all help me out?

Much appreciated & Thanks, 
Ronny McNamara

Comment: The containers must be linked somehow, are you using similar material elements in both the main view and the dialog view? and if so, are you manipulating the style to these elements programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate all the support!

The answer lied in a piece of undeleted useless CSS code that we forgot to comment!

The problem was a CSS code that limited the max height of the .

if you're facing the same solution, make sure to examine every single tag with inspect element under a microscope lol!

Regards,
Ronny McNamara

Comment: No problem, glad you were able to figure this out. Next time I will convert comment to answer if the comment helped. I did not have enough information about your project at the time to post as an answer even though my suspicions were spot on.

Comment: @Marshal you were right! i could not upload the code for the sake of confidentiality!

Comment: understandable, but my comment assisted in providing you a solution even though code was not provided... next time I will convert to answer so that I have the opportunity to gain the rep.

Comment: without a doubt. I'm kinda new to the way it works. If I had known how to make your comment an answer, I would've!

Comment: no worries. Just giving feedback is all. You don't have the ability to convert comment to answer, but most users if not all in this scenario will post an answer for you to accept.

Comment: I experienced a similar issue, but I was able to fix it by removing `overflow-x: hidden` in body